# Android Camera won't take picture depending on what is after it in code

Tags: android, multithreading, concurrency, camera, deadlock

I have the following code with which I'm trying to take a picture and save some of the photo's information into a database. The database portion has been thoroughly tested and works fine in all other circumstances. Unfortunately, if I uncomment the commented code below, my code times out. For some reason, if there is code following the `this.camera.takePicture()` method, `takePicture()` won't call the overridden `onPictureTaken` method at all (the first thing it's supposed to do is print out a line of text, but it doesn't even do that). If no code follows it, it works fine.

Before installing the latch, I would get an error because `ph.getPhoto()` was returning `null` (ph's `.photo` member variable wasn't yet set by `onPictureTaken()`, because it hadn't yet been called). After installing the latch, it will wait until timeout (or forever, if no timeout value is specified).

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing?

```
    public void takePicture(View view) throws Exception {
        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        System.out.println("Taking Photo!");
        PhotoHandler photoHandler = new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext(),latch);
        this.camera.takePicture(null, null, photoHandler);

    /* PhotoHandler has an overridden "onPictureTaken()" method which releases the latch as its final
     * action; however, its first instruction is to print a confirmation that it has been accessed.
     * Unfortunately, for some reason, onPictureTaken() is not called if the following code is
     * uncommented; it deadlocks for the five seconds before timing out. However, with out the following,
     * the camera.takePicture method invokes onPictureTaken() and it works just fine. */


//      latch.await(5,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
//      DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
//      Photo p = photoHandler.getPhoto();
//      db.addPhoto(p);
//      List<Photo> photos = new ArrayList<Photo>();
//      photos.add(p);
//      this.addPhotosToMap(photos);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`onPictureTaken()` is (afaik) executed on the main / UI thread. If your `takePicture` method is also exectued there than it must happen simply because a thread cannot wait for itself.

Besides, you must not block the mainthread or your Activity will ANR.

If you move the commented code (minus that latch) to `onPictureTaken()` then everything should be fine. Those `onSomethingHappened` callbacks are made exactly for that task

Comment: The `takePicture` method is part of the main activity, and it's executed by a button. I have no idea how to check which thread it's part of. I would agree that it should have to happen; however, like I said, it doesn't happen unless the latter portion of the code is removed. It doesn't even execute the first instruction, which is a simple sysout.

Secondly, I know I shouldn't block the thread, but the getPhoto() method shouldn't execute before the method that sets the photo. I can move that around later or remove the latch altogether, but that doesn't fix my problem right now.

Comment: Thirdly, I originally had the database code in `onPictureTaken()`, but it didn't like that either, so I moved it around in an attempt to figure out what was wrong. I can move it back, but it doesn't solve the problem. Anyway, besides the db stuff, the rest of that currently-commented-out code is responsible for populating the mapview with the new photo's marker. Should that not stay part of the UI? And if not, how should I tell onPictureTaken to manipulate the UI?

Comment: `onPictureTaken` isn't executed before the picture is taken. You know that it is once the method is called (like you know that the button was pressed once you get `onClick`). Since callbacks are executed on the main thread you can simply set the image for the UI from there.  `onPictureTaken` is UI part. And the way how you modify the UI is the same you would do in e.g. `onCreate` (which is exactly such a callback itself)

Comment: I rewrote the program to do the filepath generation in the Activity's takePicture method instead of onPictureTaken() to avoid the problem altogether (I never have to get any information out of onPictureTaken). I still do the filesystem work in onPictureTaken() and there are no problems, so it is unrelated to the speed of the filesystem (anyway, it shouldn't take a minute to write a tiny image file to an SD card, so file I/O isn't causing the problem).

Answer (score 0):

Put all of your post-processing (i.e., the code you have commented out) into the appropriate callback, not after takePicture.  And put slow actions such as file system access into a background thread (e.g., AsyncTask).

Comment: Most of the post processing is responsible for changing the UI. I originally had the db code as part of the `onPictureTaken()` method, but I moved it out to see if it was the cause of the problem. I can put it back, but it won't fix my problem. Anyway, I can execute all of the filesystem stuff instantly--that's not a problem atm (thanks for the advice though)--with the latter portion of the code commented out.

Why would having code after `camera.takePicture()` affect whether or not it calls back to `onPictureTaken()`?

Comment: Maybe the code is running, but has an error.  It's possible for that code to be reached before the picture data is ready.

Comment: Okay, after 5 seconds, probably not.